# getting the value from a api xml format response return array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I parse an xml response from an API by.

```
$responseXML2 = curl_seasson($url['phemail']);
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($responseXML2);
```

to get the value from a xml

```
$alltimeratio1 = $xml2->monitor['alltimeuptimeratio'];
```

you can check the xml format response of the [api here](http://api.uptimerobot.com/getMonitors?apiKey=m776701721-d532d1d2d020749423d80200). now as you can see in the api response (check the attach link), im getting the value of alltimeuptimeratio and then put it in an array and then echo it as a json_encode. (refer to the code below)

```
$array = array("ph" => array("phweb" => $status, "phemail" => $status2, "alltimeratio1" => $alltimeratio1));
echo json_encode($array);
```

assume I have the $status and $status2 content already stored in that array above and what I get when I run this in my browser is. (refer to the code below)

```
{"ph":{"phweb":"boxup","phemail":"boxup","alltimeratio1":{"0":"99.73"}}}
```

my question is, why the alltimeratio1 is ":{"0":"99.73}"? if i try to echo $alltimeratio1, I get the 99.73 without the 0. is there a way I could store only 99.73 (without the 0) in the array set?

I expect the array structure result to be like this

```
{"ph":{"phweb":"boxup","phemail":"boxup","alltimeratio1":"99.73"}}
```

any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using ajax to parse the return response then you can access that value by identifying the second array key which is in youralltimeratio array place. for example.

```
var thearray = new Array(result["ph"]["phweb"], result["ph"]["phemail"], result["ph"]["alltimeratio1"][0]);
```

or simply as

```
var theValueOfTheAllTimeRatio = thearray[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you are parsing the XML response, but it seems that its treated as a array. This is the reason you get this `{"0":"99.73"}`

I try with a simple script and work well, so the problem I think its about parsing XML.

```
$alltimeratio1 = "99.73";

$status = $status2 = "boxup";

$array = array("ph" => array("phweb" => $status, "phemail" => $status2, "alltimeratio1" => $alltimeratio1));

echo json_encode($array);
```

Response:

```
 {"ph":{"phweb":"boxup","phemail":"boxup","alltimeratio1":"99.73"}}
```

Comment: any suggestion how to parse it right so that I could get the right value? this is the way I parse the xml response "$responseXML2 = curl_seasson($url['phemail']);
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($responseXML2);"

Comment: please, provide XML example in the question, because right now api is under maintenance